# autodoc directive works locally but not on readthedocs

Tags: git, github, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

My repo is located on github here: https://github.com/AshleySetter/optoanalysis

And the docs are in https://github.com/AshleySetter/optoanalysis/tree/master/optoanalysis/docs

ReadTheDocs doesn't fail but the produced documentation (hosted here: https://optoanalysis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) doesn't display the doc strings that should be produced by the `..autodoc::` command.

However it runs fine locally and displays the documentation when I open the build/html/index.html file.

On ReadTheDocs it looks like:

[image: READTHEDOCS documentation]

Whereas the locally built html file looks like so:

[image: locally hosted documentation]

Why might this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have modules written in Cython and compiled to C. I think [ReadTheDocs doesn't support C extensions](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#i-get-import-errors-on-libraries-that-depend-on-c-modules). You have to protect you imports to be generated at ReadTheDocs.

Something like [this](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-change-behavior-for-read-the-docs):

```
import os
if 'READTHEDOCS' not in os.environ:
    import cython_generated_ext
```